# Vertically aligning divs in html

Tags: html, css

I have the following html. I need to align the .faf-text fields to each other vertically without using a table.

```
<div id="faf-field-2" class="faf-field faf-field-input ">
<div class="faf-name"> Vendor </div>
<div class="faf-text"> Brocade </div>
</div>
<div id="faf-field-6" class="faf-field faf-field-input ">
<div class="faf-name"> Platform </div>
<div class="faf-text"> ADX </div>
</div>
<div id="faf-field-7" class="faf-field faf-field-input ">
<div class="faf-name"> Version </div>
<div class="faf-text"> 12.4 </div>
</div>
```

An example of what the layout should be like is below :

```
Vendor   Brocade
Platform ADX
Version  12.4
```

Thanks

Comment: make a js fiddle along with your css you have tried :)

Comment: is there a jsfiddle for that, and what have you tried allready?

Comment: draw it using pipe-lines and dashes and provide us so that we can understand what exactly u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `display: table` to make your  elements act like a table.

Use `display: table-row;` for the container `<div>` tags  to make it behave like a `<tr>` and `display: table-cell;` for the  elements inside to make it behave like `<td>`.

Something like this:

```
.faf-field-input{
    display: table-row;
}
.faf-field-input div{
    display: table-cell;
}
.faf-name{
    width: 80px; /*for testing*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6ACbp/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
float: left
```

for both classes.
An ex:

```
.faf-name{
width: 200px;
float: left;
/* other CSS may come here */
}
```

in the same way,

```
.faf-text{
width: 200px;
float: left;
/* other CSS may come here */
}
```

It would have been easier and clearer if you have provided jsfiddle. Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Just Use this css property so faf-text fields to each other vertically without using a table.

```
.faf-field{display:table-cell;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6ACbp/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks to me that you are displaying tabular data.

So it's perfectly good to use a table.